# How does DoubleClick HTML5 Validator know the dimensions of my banner ad?

Tags: double-click, banner, banner-ads

I'm just curious, when you upload a banner to https://h5validator.appspot.com/dcm#/asset, what line of code does it use to detect the dimensions of the banner.

I have a banner that is 160x600, but the HTML5 Validator is detecting it as 300x250.  My body, and my container are set to a width: 160px and height: 600px

I'm not sure where else to look. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious, the answer is that the banner needs a meta tag.

From Google DoubleClick's [Developer Guidelines](https://support.google.com/dcm/partner/answer/3145300?hl=en#dev):

Fixed: for fixed dimensions, (such as 300x250), enter fixed the dimensions as shown below.

```
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=300,height=250">
```

Flexible: for flexible dimensions, enter a 0 for the width and a 0 for the height:

```
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=0,height=0">
```

Flexible width: for a flexible width and a fixed height, enter a 0 for the width and a fixed value (such as 250) for the height:

```
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=0,height=250">
```

Flexible height: For a flexible height and a fixed width, enter a fixed value (such as 300) for the width and a 0 for the height:

```
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=0,height=250">
```